Mass Transit Test Environment Issue when using Fast Endpoints in .Net
I am having an issue with adding FastEnpoints to my integration test project. Note it is working for my project but not in the test environment.
It fails on this line in my Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddFastEndpoints

I am getting the following errors:

Here is my OrderApplicationFactoryClass:
public class OrderApiApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime where TEntryPoint : Program // : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private const string Database = "master";
    private const string Username = "sa";
    private const string Password = "yourStrong(!)Password";
    private string _connectionString;
    private const ushort MsSqlPort = 1433;
    private const ushort RabbitMqPort = 5672; 
    private readonly MsSqlContainer _mssqlContainer;
    private readonly RabbitMqContainer _rabbitMqContainer;

public HttpClient HttpClient { get; private set; } = default!;

private const string RabbitMqUsername = "guest";
private const string RabbitMqPassword = "guest";

    public OrderApiApplicationFactory()
    {
        _mssqlContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
            .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
            // Remove static port binding and let Docker assign random ports
            .WithPortBinding(0, MsSqlPort)
            .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y") 
            .WithEnvironment("SA_PASSWORD", Password)
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(MsSqlPort))
            .Build();

        _rabbitMqContainer = new RabbitMqBuilder()
            .WithImage("rabbitmq:3-management-alpine") 
            .WithPortBinding(5672, RabbitMqPort) // Bind RabbitMQ's default port to the specified host port
            .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER", RabbitMqUsername)
            .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS", RabbitMqPassword)
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer()
                .UntilPortIsAvailable(RabbitMqPort) // Wait until the specified host port is available
                .UntilPortIsAvailable(15672)) // Wait until the management port is available
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _mssqlContainer.StartAsync();
        await _rabbitMqContainer.StartAsync();
       _rabbitMqContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(RabbitMqPort);
        GetDatabaseConnectionString();
        var x = _rabbitMqContainer.Hostname;

        HttpClient = CreateClient();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("testcontainersappsettings.json")
       .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
           ["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"] =  _connectionString,
           ["RabbitMQConfiguration:Config:HostName"] = _rabbitMqContainer.Hostname
       })
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();

            configurationBuilder.AddConfiguration(configuration);
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            RemoveDbContextOptions<BookyWooksOrderDbContext>(services);
            //RemoveDbContextOptions<IntegrationEventLogDbContext>(services);

            AddDbContext<BookyWooksOrderDbContext>(services);
            //AddDbContext<IntegrationEventLogDbContext>(services);
        });
    }

    private void RemoveDbContextOptions<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : DbContext
    {
        var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
            d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<T>));

        if (descriptor != null)
            services.Remove(descriptor);
    }

    private void AddDbContext<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : DbContext
    {
        services.AddDbContext<T>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString,
                builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(T).Assembly.FullName));
        });
    }
    private string GetDatabaseConnectionString()
    {
        _connectionString = _mssqlContainer.GetConnectionString(); // $"Server={_mssqlContainer.Hostname},{_mssqlContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(MsSqlPort)};Database={Database};User Id={Username};Password={Password};TrustServerCertificate=True";
        return _connectionString;
    }

    public new async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _mssqlContainer.DisposeAsync();
        await _rabbitMqContainer.DisposeAsync();
    }
}

Would anyone know what is causing this issue? I cannot see where and if I am using different versions of assemblies.

The fact something is referencing "GreenPipes" would be a sure sign that something is referencing a significantly older version of MassTransit.

Thanks @ChrisPatterson for your response. Is there a way for me to find out what is referencing it? I cannot see what it is.

Look through all your references/packages and see what's referencing something obsolete.

@ChrisPatterson If it works for my order application but not in my test environment project. Then it would have to be the test project that is referencing the obsolete package?

I’m not sure how though. Because my test project references the order project which references my message project which is using mass transit . So it should work…

Thanks @ChrisPatterson for your help. I had to update one of my testing packages. The issue has now nbeen resolved. Thank you.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
